# What is the name of the hyperbolic model?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading about the isometries of the hyperbolic plane, but I am being somewhat confused with the names of the models: Poincaré disk, Poncaré semiplane, Lorenz model, Klein model, etc. I have the following metrics:

\begin{align*}
g_{e}&=dx^2+e^{2x}dy^2\\
g_{P}&=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}\\
g_{\cosh}&=dx^2+\cosh^2xdy^2\\
g_{D}&=4\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{(1-(x^2+y^2))^2}
\end{align*}

Can someone help me to identify the names please or their exact definitions? I have already managed to verify that they are all isometric immersions of each other, but I do not know their names and I would like to know them. Thank you.

Comment: Start with the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, with that I have found two, but these two are still pending $g_e$ and $g_{\cosh}$. Do you have any suggestive literature?

Comment: Searching for _models of the hyperbolic plane_ finds lots of links. Wikipedia is just the first. Do your homework before asking here.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have looked in formal books such as Do Carmo, Spivak, Stoker etc ... but I have not found exactly what I am looking for, the names of those two models. The others are known but I had to give context to the question, perhaps that way it will be better understood.

Comment: Here's a guess that you can try to confirm: The two remaining ones have the property that $y= c$ are geodesics. It looks like one has the property that $x=0$ is a geodesic, and $y=c$ are geodesics that are orthogonal to $x=0$. With other one, the curve $x=0$ is a horocycle and the geodesics $y=c$ are orthogonal to $x=0$.

Comment: @Deane Interesting I had not realized it, thank you! But the objective of the question is above all to know if there are known names for these two models.

Comment: Both can be found here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_systems_for_the_hyperbolic_plane

Comment: So they don't have a specific name, but they are a consequence of necessity. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, they're both "whole plane models" and not conformal. There's one more you didn't list, the one called "polar coordinate system".

Comment: I've worked with this model a fair amount. It has its uses, and it turns up in some interesting contexts. But for all that, it doesn't have a name that I know.

Comment: @LeeMosher Can you recommend a book or article where I can read more about these two metrics $g_e$ and $g_{\cosh}$?

Comment: The metric $g_e$ arises as the $x,z$ planes of 3-dimensional solv geometry; see for example page 470 of Peter Scott's paper *The geometries of 3-manifolds. Bull. London Math. Soc. 15 (1983), no. 5*, and in an upside down version as the $y,z$ planes of that same geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These metrics are known to me by the following names:

- $dx^2 + e^{2x}dy^2$ is the *horocyclic coordinate system*. The constant-$x$ lines are concentric horocycles and the constant-$y$ lines are unit-speed geodesics perpendicular to the horocycles.
- $(dx^2+dy^2)/y^2$ is the *Poincaré half-plane model*, defined only for $y > 0$. The constant-$y$ lines are concentric horocycles and the constant-$x$ lines are geodesics perpendicular to the horocycles, this time not unit speed however.
- $dx^2 + \cosh(x)^2 dy^2$ are *geodesic coordinates* or *Fermi coordinates*. The line $x=0$ is a unit-speed geodesic, and the constant-$y$ lines are unit-speed geodesics perpendicular to the first. The spherical analogue is the equirectangular projection with metric $dx^2 + \cos(x)^2 dy^2$.
- $4(dx^2+dy^2)/(1-(x^2+y^2))^2$ is the *Poincaré disk model*, defined only on the unit disk, where geodesics are circular arcs perpendicular to the unit circle. The spherical analogue is the stereographic projection with metric $4(dx^2+dy^2)/(1+(x^2+y^2))^2$.

More metrics you mentioned:

- $(dx^2+dy^2)/(1-(x^2+y^2))+(xdx+ydy)^2/(1-(x^2+y^2))^2$ is the *Beltrami-Klein model* aka *Klein model*. Its spherical analogue is the gnomonic projection $(dx^2+dy^2)/(1+(x^2+y^2))-(xdx+ydy)^2/(1+(x^2+y^2))^2$.
- The hyperboloid model is not a model defined by a metric on $\mathbb R^2$, but by the metric $dx^2+dy^2-dz^2$ on one sheet of the two-sheeted hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$ in $\mathbb R^3$. The spherical analogue of this model is simply the embedding of the 2-sphere into euclidean 3-space.